# Unity "You are currently offline" error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the exact error I get while using Unity:

[image]

Everyone has said to disable your VPN/firewall/security. I've done all of this, and even re-downloaded, but I'm still not able to use Unity online; I'm only allowed to use it in offline mode.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix to this?
I've had the same and haven't been able to find a solution
Unity 2017.4.1f1

Comment: @JamesVeug:  If you still need the answer, please see my solution in the answer below. It works for me.

Comment: @Thanh I tried your instructions a while back and it never worked for me. I've posted the solution I found that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. My issue wasn't firewall but the wrong time-zone on my account. I went to my account page and update everything correctly resolved the issue. Some servers are configured in a manner where they will reject any requests from a wrongly configured time-zone due to potential cyber attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In **Unity 2017** and **Unity 2018**, I used to do this to fix the problem:

(1)  ***Log out of your Unity account from your Unity application:***

Go To "Unity" menu -> click on "Manage License" -> Click on "My Account" -> Click on "Sign out".

(2) Then exit Unity application.

(3) Relaunch Unity.

**(4) Try to logon to your Unity account again from your Unity application.**

Next, try to access Unity store again. **Be very patient and wait for 2 or 3 minutes**, and the internet connection will eventually be established from your Unity editor on your computer to Unity asset store, and everything will be fine.

Sometimes, I have to repeat this procedure 2 times to make it work. But, it works in the end (very strangely).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many solutions and this worked the best. However some of the other instructions mentioned on other sites could have affected the instructions below.

- Log out of your Account in unity
- Close Asset store page if you have it open
- Open Asset store page
- Log into your Unity Account using the Asset Store window
- You will now be able to use the store

Answer (score 0):

I recently got that error in Mac OS. I also did the solutions above but didn't help. Try connecting to asset store in a browser and set your info, especially your nickname, that solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

Open Unity Hub as administrator

Comment: is that it? Does that do all that is needed?

Answer (score 0):

In **Unity 2019**, the solution is very easy as follow:

(1) Click on the "**Asset Store**" tap in Unity.

(2) On that "**Asset Store**" tap, find the symbol that looks like the " ***three vertical dot*** " located at the top right corner of the "**Asset Store**" tab.

(3) Then, click on that " ***three vertical dot*** " symbol. You will see a drop-down menu.

(4) Next, on that drop-down menu, click on the "**Reload**" button.

Now, Unity will automatically re-connect or re-logon to Unity asset store. For most people, this will fix the issue at this point.

However, if you still can't logon at this point, then you may need to install "**Unity hub**", which is a new feature in **Unity 2019**. This will fix the issue for sure.

(**Note**: This solution works perfectly well for **Unity 2019** all the times. However, it may not work very reliably every single times for **Unity 2017** and **Unity 2018**, but you still can try as it may work for you.)